# How to draw the bar graph on both side of x-axis in android

Tags: android, graph, drawing, bar-chart, achartengine

I am working on the application which measures the data usage of application/process running in the android device.

I want represent this data usage in terms bar graph which will draw along the x-axis. Upper side of the x-axis (Red bar) will show the data which transmitted, and lower side (Green bar) will show the data which received.

Attached screenshot may clear your doubts.

[image]

I also checked with the popular graph drawing libraries Ex: [`AChartEngine`](http://www.achartengine.org/) , [`AndroidPlot`](http://androidplot.com/) and [`afreechart`](https://code.google.com/p/afreechart/) but it not having support to draw such type of graph.

Is it possible to draw a such type of graph? Any suggestion always welcome..

Comment: What makes you think this is not possible with AChartEngine. You just need a little bit of imagination.

Comment: @Dan: Thanks for the information.. Can you suggest any other libraries for that?

Answer (score 0):

try making 2 XYSeries add them on the same index and set the type to 
`TYPE.STACKED`
if i'm correct that will stack them togheter and if you change the color of them it should be possible